# Receiving parse error from SageMaker Multi Model Endpoint using TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

We are currently moving our models from single model endpoints to multi model endpoints within AWS SageMaker. After deploying the Multi Model Endpoint using prebuilt TensorFlow containers I receive the following error when calling the predict() method:

`{"error": "JSON Parse error: The document root must not be followed by other value at offset: 17"}`

I invoke the endpoint like this:

```
data = np.random.rand(n_samples, n_features)

predictor = Predictor(endpoint_name=endpoint_name)
prediction = predictor.predict(data=serializer.serialize(data), target_model=model_name)
```

My function for processing the input is the following:

```
def _process_input(data, context):
    data = data.read().decode('utf-8')
    data = [float(x) for x in data.split(',')]
    return json.dumps({'instances': [data]})
```

For the training I configured my container as follows:

```
tensorflow_container = TensorFlow(
    entry_point=path_script,
    framework_version='2.4',
    py_version='py37',
    instance_type='ml.m4.2xlarge',
    instance_count=1,
    role=EXECUTION_ROLE,
    sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session,
    hyperparameters=hyperparameters)

tensorflow_container.fit()
```

For deploying the endpoint I first initializing a Model from a given Estimator and then a MultiDataModel:

```
model = estimator.create_model(
            role=EXECUTION_ROLE, 
            image_uri=estimator.training_image_uri(),
            entry_point=path_serving)

mdm = MultiDataModel(
        name=endpoint_name, 
        model_data_prefix=dir_model_data,
        model=model, 
        sagemaker_session=sagemaker.Session())

mdm.deploy(
        initial_instance_count=1, 
        instance_type=instance_type,
        endpoint_name=endpoint_name)
```

Afterwards the single models are added using:

```
mdm.add_model(
    model_data_source=source_path,
    model_data_path=model_name)
```

Thank you for any hints and help.

Answer (score 0):

This issue usually occurs in case you either have damaged or malformed JSON data. Recommend you running it past JSON validator https://jsonlint.com/

I work at AWS and my opinions are my own - Thanks,Raghu